# Conditional delayed processing

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, data-structures, threadpool

I have created a new thread pool and a new associated listener under glassfish. The thread pool has a maximum capacity of 100 threads. I have a scheduled job running every night which should trigger a HTTP GET request from remote client. Note that the scheduled job is **NOT** a HTTP client. It however triggers remote HTTP clients to make a HTTP GET requests. The number of requests can exeed more than 100. The scheduled job should run in a un-interrupted way even if the number of request exceed 100. Below is the psuedo code

```
class ScheduledJob{

    public executeJob(){
    {
        for(i=0; i<=numberOfTasks; i++)
        {
            connectToTheClientsAndAskThemToFireHTTPGetRequests();
        }
    }

}
```

The way I would like to design the solution is to make the **executeJob** method execute in a non-blocking way.That would mean 100 requests are fired initially and the rest of the requests are cached. On receipt of 200 OK, I would then throttle the remaining requests. Note that the HTTP request could take a few seconds as the response HTTP GET is a 20MB binary file. The question here is is there any out of the box solution (data-structure) to perform my caching and triggering business logic OR can anyone suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a `Runnable` that takes a concurrent queue of `GetTasks` (or whatever you want to name the wrapper for the HTTP GET request data).  `executeJob()` fills the queue with all of the `GetTasks`, constructs a thread pool of 100 threads, and submits 100 `Runnables` that share the same concurrent queue.  The `Runnables` will poll the queue until it is empty, at which point they terminate.

```
public class GetTask {}

public class GetTaskExecutor implements Runnable {
   private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GetTask> queue;

   public GetTaskExecutor(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GetTask> queue) {
     this.queue = queue;
   }

   public void run() {
     GetTask task = null;
     while((task = queue.poll()) != null) {
       // do work
     }
   }
}

class ScheduledJob{
    public boolean executeJob(){
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GetTask> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        for(i=0; i<=numberOfTasks; i++) {
            queue.offer(new GetTask());
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            service.execute(new GetTaskExecutor(queue));
        }
        return service.awaitTermination(4, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}
```

An alternative is to create one `GetTaskExecutor` per `GetTask` and submit them all to the `ExecutorService` - you're using a fixed thread pool so at most 100 tasks will execute at a time.

```
public class GetTaskExecutor implements Runnable {
   private final GetTask task;

   public GetTaskExecutor(GetTask task) {
     this.task = task;
   }

   public void run() {
     // do work on single task
   }
}

class ScheduledJob{
    public boolean executeJob(){
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        for(i=0; i<=numberOfTasks; i++) {
            service.execute(new GetTaskExecutor(new GetTask());
        }
        return service.awaitTermination(4, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}
```